# Silverlight 4: Dispatcher-error when using Calendar or DatePicker

Tags: silverlight, calendar, datepicker

I read so many good answers on this site, so I never had to ask something.
Now I have a problem I cant find a answer. I'm programming a Windows App für 7.1 and try to use a Calendar Control, I dont care that much if its Calendar or DatePicker.

But whenever I change the value there, I get the following error:

"This type of Collection does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread."

Since im quite beginner, I dont do anything fancy with Threads and I didnt find anything about this error in the web, so I guess, this must be a unique error at my environment.

Has anyone a idea, where this error can come from?

Thanks for your responses

Müller Matthias

Comment: Do you make this change in your code behind or from your interface

Comment: Hi, in the interface at the moment.
All Im doing is in the XAML:
[Code]
xmlns:basics="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
    
<basics:Calendar x:Name="cal" />
[/Code]

Answer (score 0):

You should use DatePicker from SDK namespace,

http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/samplebrowser/#/?sref=System.Windows.Controls.Calendar

I can also suggest Telerik's silverlight controls
http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/

```
<UserControl  xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" x:Class="CalendarExample.Page"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" FontSize="11"
Width="600" Height="750">

<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" >
    <!-- A basic Calendar. -->
    <TextBlock  Width="100" 
               Text="Calendar with date ranges defined:" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5" />
    <sdk:Calendar x:Name="cal" />

    <!-- A Calendar does not highlight today's date. -->
        <TextBlock  Width="100" 
               Text="Calendar that does not highlight today's date:" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5"/>
        <sdk:Calendar x:Name="cal2" Canvas.Left="270" Canvas.Top="100" 
                    IsTodayHighlighted="false" />
    </StackPanel>
    <!-- Two DatePicker controls, one using the default Short date format -->
    <!-- and the other using the Long date format. -->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <TextBlock Width="200" Margin="5" 
               Text="DatePicker with Short date format and Calendar event handlers:" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <sdk:DatePicker x:Name="dp1" Height="20" Width="200" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <TextBlock Width="200" Margin="5"
               Text="DatePicker with Long date format and DateSelected event handler:" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <sdk:DatePicker Height="20" x:Name="dp2" SelectedDateFormat="Long" Width="200"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <!-- Output TextBlock -->
    <TextBlock x:Name="text1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Width="350" Margin="5" />

    <!-- A Calendar to demonstrate multiple selection. -->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <TextBlock  Width="200" Margin="5"
               Text="Calendar with multiple selections and blackout dates:" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <sdk:Calendar x:Name="cal3" />
    </StackPanel>
 </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the respone.
Interesting enought, when I add the reference like this and add the datepicker, it gets me this error, when I try to load the page:
"The type 'DatePicker' was not found. [Line: 40 Position: 33]"

Am I missing a specific reference?

Comment: System.Windows.Controls.Data / System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input / System.Windows.Controls

Comment: Firstly you should install SDK http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28359

Comment: Allready reinstalled it, but when I use the datePicker, the same error appears.